# Is it true that $\text{null} \, T \cap \text{range} \, T \cap \text{null} \, S = \{ 0 \}$ for arbitrary linear maps $S, T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $U$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, that $S ∈ L(V, W )$, and that $T ∈ L(U, V )$. I'm trying to prove that $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{null}(ST ) = \operatorname{dim} \operatorname{null}(T ) + \operatorname{dim} (\operatorname{range}(T ) ∩ \operatorname{null}(S))$.

First I realized that for a vector $x$ to be in $\operatorname{null}(ST)$, it can

(1) be in $\operatorname{null} T$, in which case $Sx=0$ (since $S$ is a linear map) and thus $x \in \operatorname{null}(ST)$

(2) get mapped to an element of $\operatorname{range}T$ that happens to be in the null space of $S$.

Hence $\operatorname{null}T$ and $\operatorname{range}(T ) ∩ \operatorname{null}(S)$ combine to make $\operatorname{null}(ST)$, i.e.  $$\operatorname{null}T + \operatorname{range}(T ) ∩ \operatorname{null}(S) = \operatorname{null}(ST).$$

Now, taking $\text{dim}$s, I get

$$\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{null}T + \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{range}(T ) ∩ \operatorname{null}(S)) - \operatorname{dim}(\text{null} \, T \cap \text{range} \, T \cap \text{null} \, S) = \operatorname{dim}\operatorname{null}(ST).$$

It seems like for the theorem to hold, we must have that $\text{dim}(\text{null} \, T \cap \text{range} \, T \cap \text{null} \, S) = 0$, i.e. that $\text{null} \, T \cap \text{range} \, T \cap \text{null} \, S  = \{ 0 \}$ for arbitrary linear maps $S, T$. Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how go about conceptualizing and proving this?

Comment: I think by null you mean ker where null = dim ker

Comment: What does it mean for you the intersection, say, of $null\,T$ and $range\, T$ if they belong to completely different spaces, $U$ and $V$?

Comment: @GReyes That's what I was thinking about; if we can guarantee that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint (with the exception of the $0$ element), then we're done. But what if there is overlap, or if $U=V=W$?

Comment: @Tiwa I think what GReyes is pointing out is that range(T) belongs to a different space, so you cannot eg combine it (or a subspace of it) with the kernel of T, at least not with vector addition of elements which is what I presume '+' means in this context

Comment: @CalvinKhor I'm not sure I understand. If $U=V=W$, then aren't the range and kernel (this is equivalent to null space, yes?) of T subspaces of the same vector space?

Comment: The question is not phrased with $U=V=W$, so what gives you the ability to write $ker T + range T\cap ker S$, in the general case?

Comment: @CalvinKhor We can write that in the general case because of cases (1) and (2) above, right? I don't see how it simplifies in the case that $U = V = W$, however.

Comment: No, say $T$ is the linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ into the space of polynomials of degree at most 4 given by $T(a,b) = ax^3+b$. The range is a collection of polynomials. The kernel is a collection of points in the plane. Range + kernel =......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $u_1,\dots,u_n \in U$ is a basis of the kernel of $T$ and $v_1,\dots,v_m \in V$ is a basis of the space formed by intersecting the range of $T$ with the kernel of $S$. As the $v_i$s are in the range of $T$, they have preimages in $U$. Pick one preimage for each $v_i$;  you can group them with the earlier $u_i$s to get a collection of linearly independent (why?) vectors $u_1,\dots,u_{n+m}\in U$. This implies that the nullity of $ST$ is at least $n+m$.

Conversely let $u\in U$ be an arbitrary vector in the kernel of $ST$. As you noted, it is either in the kernel of $T$ or is mapped by $T$ into the kernel of $S$. Thus it is in the span of $u_1,\dots,u_{n+m}$ (does it matter that we chose specific preimages?), and so the nullity is at most $n+m$.